# Spring properly creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Please, help me a little bit. I have created corresponding database and tried to annotate Bean using Constructor and `@Autowired` annotaion. However
I'm getting below errors

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in uz.course.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in uz.course.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$28/1955102821.getObject(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4641)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1737)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$240(TCPTransport.java:683)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$18/163951897.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> Here is my HibernateConfig.java file where nested errors created.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties", "classpath:hibernate.properties"})
@PropertySource(name = "hibernate", value = "classpath:hibernate.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

private Environment environment;

@Autowired
public HibernateConfig(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    try {
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.password"));
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(environment.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", Integer.class));
        dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(environment.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", Integer.class));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(environment.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", Integer.class));
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(environment.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", Integer.class));
        dataSource.getProperties().put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy",
                environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy"));
        dataSource.getProperties().put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",
                environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("uz.course.hibernate.domain");
    sessionFactoryBean.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl());

    Properties properties = (Properties) ((StandardServletEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources().get("hibernate").getSource();
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
    sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
}

@Lazy
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = null;
    try {
        transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return transactionManager;
}

@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return transactionManager();
}
```

Comment: **Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution** makes it look like an issue with the database connection

Comment: Separate note: If you're already using spring-boot, why need to define your own bean as I don't see anything that spring-boot isn't doing on it's own?

Comment: It does sound like a database connection issue.  What database are you trying to use?

Comment: I'm using postges, my domain class regonizing database tables. maybe i have an issue with dataSource configuration